# Publishing Targets Tridion 2011

Tags: tridion, publishing, tridion-2011

We are using Tridion 2011 SP1 and DD4T framework.

We have websites in both Staging and Live servers. We have published to both the servers from Tridion 2011 SP1 using different targets (Staging and Live). Now i am planning to add staging servers into Live target, So while publishing to Live it will be published to staging also. I am not going to use Staging target after this.

Here my question is. Will it create any problem or any issues in this. Does it have any disadvantage?

Thanks,
Jagadeesh.

Answer (score 8):

So, all you want to do is to publish to Staging *also* when you publish to Live?

If this is all you want to do, then the easiest is to chain both Publication Targets with the same Target Type. Open the Staging Publication Target and in the advanced tab, link it with the Live Target type (and unlink it from the Staging Target Type).

You should probably also remove the Staging Target Type so as to not confuse your editors.

PS - I am answering here, but your question is not a Stack Overflow/Programming question. You should have asked this in [serverfault](http://www.serverfault.com/questions/tagged/tridion) instead.

2nd part of the question: Will it cause issues?
Think why you had staging to begin with, since you're going to lose that now. You are probably removing the ability to implement Experience Manager (ex-SiteEdit), but maybe that's not a requirement. Staging is also typically a smaller environment. If you're doing this because you need more capacity on your Live server, then you should have considered buying a new server instead, and linking it to the same database (since you're using DD4T there's no nastyness related to file system replication or multiple deployers).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Sorry for the confusion. i am planning to remove staging target and planning to add staging deployer to Live target. So while publishing using Live target, It will be published to staging and also i m planning to use same broker DB for both Live and staging. I can add the staging deployer directly to Live target but to ensure is this correct approach?.I heared if we change the publication target the tcm id of the target will create problem. Is it correct? If it is what will be the problem?

Comment: You cannot use 2 deployers for the same database, so be careful with what exactly you're trying to do. There will be problems, way more than can fit in here. Bottom line: don't do that. If you really need to scale up your deployers then make sure you can't publish from the same publication to both deployers. I would probably get an Infrastructure Consultant for a couple of hours to discuss the objectives you have.

Comment: DB deployer is single but the file system(content delivery) deployer is more than one. I am going to add staging file system deployer to Live target. Can we do this now?

Comment: I thought you were using DD4T? AFAIK, DD4T places everything in the database... And please don't take my word (or anyone's word) on Stack Exchange as guarantee that you can change your environments without problems

Comment: With DD4T you can publish everything to a database, but some people like to publish the binaries to the filesystem instead. That's also fine.

Comment: We are using DD4T framework only. Can you please suggest me the good approach?

Comment: Quirijin - We are publishing pgaes to the broker DB and binaries to the filesystem. So planning to use same broker DB and same target for both.

Dominic - We are using the staging only to push the code files to Preview and Staging. So to keep the website in sync we are planning to do this because here people are not using the staging website. The staging is only used for code push to Preview and Live.